# PhpSpec. Call to a member function on a non-object when mock must return an object

Tags: php, symfony, bdd, phpspec

I'm new i phpspec and trying to create dummy converter for learning purposes, but I stuck with **Call to a member function on a non-objec**t error

Here is my code:

**Conver class**

```
private $supportedFormats = ['xml', 'json'];
private $handler;

public function __construct(ConvertHandler $handler)
{
    $this->handler = $handler;
}

public function convert(array $data, $format)
{
    if (!$this->shlouldBeSupportedFormat($format)) {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
    $converter = $this->handler->getConverter($format);

    return $converter->convert($data);
}

public function shlouldBeSupportedFormat($format)
{
    if (!in_array($format, $this->supportedFormats)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**ConvertHandler class**

```
public function getConverter($format)
{
    $class = "AppBundle\Service\Converter\\".ucfirst($format).'Converter';
    if (class_exists($class)) {
        return new $class();
    } else {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
}
```

**XmlConverter class**

```
public function convert(array $data)
{
    return str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', TypeConverter::toXml($data));
}
```

This code is working. It returns string in XML format.

Now tests:

**ConvertSpec class**

```
function let(ConvertHandler $handler) {
    $this->beConstructedWith($handler);
}

function its_convert_function_should_be_valid()
{
    $this->shouldThrow('Exception')->during('convert', ['sadsa','xml']);
    $this->shouldThrow('Exception')->during('convert', [[],'bad_format']);
}

function it_should_check_if_support()
{
    $this->shlouldBeSupportedFormat('xml')->shouldReturn(true);
    $this->shlouldBeSupportedFormat('bad_format')->shouldReturn(false);
}

function it_should_covert_to_xml(ConvertHandler $handler)
{
    $this->convert(['test' => 'test'], 'xml')->shouldBeString();
    $handler->getConverter('xml')->shouldBeCalled();
}
```

**ConvertHandlerSpec class**

```
function its_get_converter_shouldBe_valid()
{
    $this->shouldThrow('Exception')->during('getConverter', ['wrong_format']);
}

function it_should_return_converter()
{
    $this->getConverter('xml')->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf('AppBundle\Service\Converter\XmlConverter');
}
```

**XmlConverterSpec class**

```
function it_should_implement()
{
    $this->shouldImplement('AppBundle\Service\Converter\ConverterInterface');
}
function it_should_convert()
{
    $this->convert(['test'=>'test'])->shouldBeString();
    $this->convert(['test'=>'test'])->shouldReturn(
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><test>test</test></root>'
        );
}
```

Error when I run a tests: 
**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function convert() on a non-object in /var/www/phpSpecTest/src/AppBundle/Service/Convert.php on line 25**

I'm already trying to fix it for second day, and looking for solution in the web. But still can't find a solution.Any suggest will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't mocked `ConverterHandler->getConverter()` method in your `let` spec method. It should be like:

```
function let(ConvertHandler $handler) {
    $xmlConverter = new XmlConverter(); // OR mock it :)
    $handler->getConverter(Argument::any())->shouldReturn($xmlConverter);
    $this->beConstructedWith($handler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now it works. So I need also mock all methods of mocked object. Again thanks :)

Comment: Not all, but used ones.